# Помогите дописать или указать на ошибку в скрипте

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = document.querySelector('#open-search-str');
var b = document.querySelector('.left-top-form');
var c = document.querySelector('#closeButton');

a.onclick = function() {
  if (b.className == "left-top-form") {
    b.className = "flex-position"
  }
  return false;
};

c.onclick = function() {
  if (b.className == "flex-position") {
    b.style.display = "none"
  }
};
```

```css
#closeButton {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-top-form {
  display: none;
}

.flex-position {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid $dk-sl;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 3px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: $sl;
  display: flex;
}

.search-type {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: inherit;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="open-search-str">
  <a href="#" class="nav-items search-item">
    Нажми на меня что бы я пропало
  </a>
  <form action="#" class="left-top-form">
    <input type="text" class="search-type" placeholder="Введите Ваш запрос и нажмите Enter">
    <button type="button" id="closeButton">&times;</button>
  </form>
</li>
```

дело в том что я когда нажимаю на слово нажми, потом закрываю форму по крестику, и хочу сново форму открыть, то она глухо молчит, с джваскриптом я не очень, я пытался писать там код но видимо что то надо возвратить, помогите прошу Вас)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас за видимость объекта отвечает класс

```
.left-top-form {
  display: none;
}
```

если он установлен, то элемента не видно. И Вы при клике по ссылке проверяете именно наличие этого класса и убираете его

```
if (b.className == "left-top-form") {
  b.className = "flex-position"
}
```

А вот при закрытии, Вы вместо того, чтобы вернуть этот класс обратно

```
if (b.className == "flex-position") {
  b.className = "left-top-form"
}
```

устанавливаете

```
b.style.display = "none"
```

Понятно, что следующая проверка

```
if (b.className == "left-top-form")
```

у Вас уже не выполнится.

А делаете Вы это, потому, что при простоя смене класса у Вас поле не скрывалось. Почему? Потому, что у Вас кнопка закрытия вложена в элемент `<li id="open-search-str">` на который навешено свое событие `onclick`, которое заставляет форму показаться.

Так вот, при клике на дочерний элемент, событие всплывает и вызывает обработчики 
этого события у всех родителей. Чтобы это не происходило, нужно отменить всплытие, вызвав метод `stopPropagation()` у объекта `event`

```js
var a = document.querySelector('#open-search-str');
var b = document.querySelector('.left-top-form');
var c = document.querySelector('#closeButton');

a.onclick = function() {
  if (b.className == "left-top-form") {
    b.className = "flex-position";
  }
  return false;
};

c.onclick = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (b.className == "flex-position") {
    b.className = "left-top-form";
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

```css
#closeButton {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-top-form {
  display: none;
}

.flex-position {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid $dk-sl;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 3px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: $sl;
  display: flex;
}

.search-type {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: inherit;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="open-search-str">
  <a href="#" class="nav-items search-item">
    Нажми на меня что бы я пропало
  </a>
  <form action="#" class="left-top-form">
    <input type="text" class="search-type" placeholder="Введите Ваш запрос и нажмите Enter">
    <button type="button" id="closeButton">&times;</button>
  </form>
</li>
```

Comment: Очень внятно и грамотно спасибо большое, изучив это, я научился чему то, огромное спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли___)))